# XMLHttpRequest responseText is always empty in Firefox WebExtension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a problem while writing a Firefox WebExtension add-on. The following code doesn't return any data (`responseText` is empty), even when the request status equals `4`. In Chrome, everything is working perfectly.

I checked even on Fiddler and I can see the request is processed (and we got a response) but it looks Firefox cannot read it?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "http://pi.com//", true);   
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
xhr.send(null);
xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

function processRequest(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
```

I really have no clue why Firefox is not getting the `responseText` filled. I already checked it with different websites, but everywhere it's the same.

Comment: Is that the page you are actually requesting? [How is your extension set up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions)?

Comment: What are your extension's permissions?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: What, *exactly*, was shown in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX)?  Did the Network monitor show the request/response?

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that we want to help. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate all the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem with such questions. Without a [mcve] the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to *guess* at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest.json try adding the key `"permissions": ["http://pi.com/"]`

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with exactly the same problem, when porting my extension from Chrome to Firefox, it was driving me crazy!

In my case it was as simple as the mailformed URL.
Instead of http://example.com/ I had to state http://**www**.example.com/